Trying to choose first audio stream of specific language in ffmpeg using python
I have .mkv files that some of them have more than 1 audio stream in the same language so i need to first map the audio streams with specific language and then use only first of them to output .mp4 file. So it would need two -map audio arguments which doesn't work in ffmpeg.
I found out that i could execute ffmpeg mapping audio with that specific language and then pipe the output to another ffmpeg command that would take the first audio stream from the first ffmpeg command and do the rest of things (scaling, burning-in subtitles, encoding it to different format), but i'm not sure how to pipe that output in python's Popen and if it is even possible in windows.
The solution i found with piping:
FFMPEG Pick First Audio Stream of Specific Language

Does this help? (you can readily modify it to use Popen) Another possibility is to use a named pipe. If you're interested and if I can find a time, I can create an example with my namedpipe package.

I'm not exactly sure how to modify that so it uses output of first Popen as -i argument in next Popen

Just realized that I commented on the solution link you provided lol. Anyway, it turned out to be pretty straight forward. See the solution below.

I would recommend PyAV instead of piping all that data into a subprocess

You can just pass the stdout of the first process to the second process. Something like this:
import subprocess as sp

p = sp.Popen(
    ['ffmpeg', '-i', inputfile, '-map', '0:a:m:language:eng',
               '-f', 'matroska', '-', 'acodec', 'copy', 'pipe:'],
    stdout=sp.PIPE,
)
sp.run(['ffmpeg', '-i', 'pipe:', '-map', '0:0', ..., outputfile],
       stdin=p.stdout)
p.terminate()


You can customize the second sp.run to do "the rest of the things". If you need video stream as well, you can add another map to the first process or add the inputfile as the second input to the second process. (the latter may be faster).
The key here is to use matroska container, which can be sent to a pipe (mp4 cannot) and copy the audio stream to save re-encoding time/loss.
P.S., you can also be "lazy" and use shell option:
sp.run(f'''ffmpeg -i {inputfile} -map 0:a -f matroska -acodec copy pipe: | 
ffmpeg -i pipe: -map 0:0 -y {outputfile}
''',shell=True)

